# Stitching large amounts of images together into one gigapixel image

Tags: image, image-processing, bitmap

So I'm trying to get a sattelite map of my township that is available for offline use, and I used [Universal Maps Downloader](http://www.allmapsoft.com/umd/) to download from bing's hybrid maps. That all worked fine, but when I used the program's built in image stitcher, I found that the resulting bitmap image was so large that it isn't a usable bitmap. Photoshop and all image viewers I can get my hands on won't view it (I'm guessing because bitmaps aren't supposed to be 6gb in size)

So I'm wondering if A.) there are any programs to stitch/view a ton (~45,000) of smaller images as one large image, or B.) any file formats that would handle an image of this size a little bit better than bitmap, and any programs that I could use to stitch the smaller images into that format (the built in stitcher in UMD only does bitmap)

Answer (score 1):

File formats: GeoTIFF. Or almost any format will do as long as you tile.

Programs: Once you hit the RAM limit and start swapping nothing is going to work if you insist on keeping it in one piece.

The correct approach is to tile and keep track of zoom level and viewport location in the viewer. Do a google search for "tiled image viewer".

Note that if you use an image format with lossy compression (e.g. JPEG) you may end up with visible tile edges because the compression on either side of the edge will yield different artifacts. A trick that usually works in that case is to render the tile in a larger canvas, then crop to tile size before writing.