# How can I write to a png/tiff file patch-by-patch?

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I want to create a png or tiff image file from a very large h5py dataset that cannot be loaded into memory all at once. So, I was wondering if there is a way in python to write to a png or tiff file in patches? (I can load the h5py dataset in slices to a `numpy.ndarray`).
I've tried using the pillow library and doing `PIL.Image.paste` giving the box coordinates, but for large images it goes out of memory.

Basically, I'm wondering if there's a way to do something like:

```
for y in range(0, height, patch_size):
    for x in range(0, width, patch_size):
        y2 = min(y + patch_size, height)
        x2 = min(x + patch_size, width)
        # image_arr is an h5py dataset that cannot be loaded completely
        # in memory, so load it in slices
        image_file.write(image_arr[y:y2, x:x2], box=(y, x, y2, x2))
```

I'm looking for a way to do this, without having the whole image loaded into memory. I've tried the pillow library, but it loads/keeps all the data in memory.

Edit: This question is not about h5py, but rather how extremely large images (that cannot be loaded into memory) can we written out to a file in patches - similar to how large text files can be constructed by writing to it line by line.

Comment: [`tifffile.memmap`](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/code/tifffile.py.html#line-517) gives you a memory-mapped numpy array stored in TIFF file. No compression or tiles though.

Comment: Could you create a bunch of separate relatively-small png/tiff images and combine them all into one big one afterwards?

Comment: Voting to close. Possible duplicate of [Does h5py read the whole file into memory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40449659/does-h5py-read-the-whole-file-into-memory)

Comment: @Colonder - this question is not about h5py, but rather writing large images to file in patches. I'm using h5py datasets for the large array that does not fit in memory, but you could use something else as well

Comment: @martineau - Combining them would require loading their data in memory. Out here, all the data cannot be loaded in memory, hence writing it out in small patches.

Comment: assassin: You're conflating size of the h5py dataset and that for the image(s). Just because one is very large doesn't mean an image created from it will be anywhere as big.

Comment: @martineau - For this question, let's assume that the image array cannot be loaded into memory when uncompressed? The purpose of this question is to figure out a good way in python to write to large images in a tiled format (or patch-by-patch).

Comment: assassin: What good is an image that's too big to fit into memory? Regardless, I doubt you can accomplish this by trying to assemble a bunch of images together in either of those two compressed formats. If instead if was un-compressed (or limited to line-oriented compression, like RLE), it would be possible to minimize memory usage when combining them by only opening the number required at any given time which contained the lines of the same rows of the final image. This would allow the lines of the final image to be joined together without reading all of them into memory all at once.

Comment: I also don't see the point in having a single image that's too big to fit into memory. How will you render it? For things like maps in which you'd conceptually have one large image, in practice they are broken up into tiles and served on demand. 

If your question isn't specific to HDF5, then it seems to be a duplicate of this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31806526/stitching-large-amounts-of-images-together-into-one-gigapixel-image

Comment: As far as I understand, TIFF nevertheless does not support images bigger as 4GB. You could get away with writing the patches into several tiff files and stacking them together as a 3D tiff file. The tiff standard defines the definition of 'strips' which are idependently compressable. I know of no library to write them. How big are the images you want to write out?

Comment: Please update the question with your requirements regarding compression or tiles. As mentioned, `tifffile.memmap` can be used to write randomly to striped, uncompressed BigTIFF files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try [tifffile.memmap](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/code/tifffile.py.html#line-517):

```
from tifffile import memmap

image_file = memmap('temp.tif', shape=(height, width), dtype=image_arr.dtype,
                    bigtiff=True)

for y in range(0, height, patch_size):
    for x in range(0, width, patch_size):
        y2 = min(y + patch_size, height)
        x2 = min(x + patch_size, width)
        image_file[y:y2, x:x2] = image_arr[y:y2, x:x2]

image_file.flush()
```

This creates a uncompressed BigTIFF file with one strip. Memory-mapped tiles are not implemented yet. Not sure how many libraries can handle that kind of file, but you can always directly read from the strip using the meta data in the TIFF tags.

Comment: @gohlke bigtiff=True does not seem to work in the latest release.

Answer (score 2):

Short answer to "if there is a way in Python to write to a png or tiff file in patches?". Well, yes - everything is possible in Python, given enough time and skill to implement it. On the other hand, NO, there is no ready-made solution for this - because it doesn't appear to be very useful.

I don't know about TIFF and a comment here says it is limited to 4GB, so this format is likely not a good candidate. PNG has no practical limit and **can** be written in chunks, so it is doable in theory - on the condition that at least one scan line of your resulting image does fit into memory.

If you *really* want to go ahead with this, here is the info that you need:
A PNG file consists of a few metadata chunks and a series of image data chunks. The latter are independent of each other and you can therefore construct a big image out of several smaller images (each of which contains a whole number of rows, a minimum of one row) by simply concatenating their image data chunks (IDAT) together and adding the needed metadata chunks (you can pick those from the first small image, except for the IHDR chunk - that one will need to be constructed to contain the final image size).

So, here is how I'd do it, if I had to (NOTE you will need some understanding of Python's `bytes` type and the methods of converting byte sequences to and from Python data types to pull this off):

- find how many rows I can fit into memory and make that the height of my "small image chunk". The width is the width of the entire final image. let's call those `width` and `small_height`
- go through my giant data set in h5py one chunk at a time (`width * small_height`), convert it to PNG and save it to disk in a temporary file, or if your image conversion library allows it - directly to a `bytes` string in memory. Then process the byte data as follows and delete it at the end:

  -- on the first iteration: walk through the PNG data one record at a time (see the PNG spec: http://www.libpng.org/pub/png/spec/1.2/png-1.2-pdg.html, it is in length-tag-value form and very easy to write code that efficiently walks over the file record by record), save ALL the records into my target file, *except*: modify IHDR to have the final image size and skip the IEND record.

  -- on all subsequent iterations: scan through the PNG data and pick only the IDAT records, write those out to the output file.
- append an IEND record to the target file.

All done - you should now have a valid humongous PNG. I wonder who or what could read that, though.